# SQL Server Table Simple Select Query taking too long

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2012, database-performance, database-administration

I have a simple table in MS SQL Server.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Personas] (
[Name] varchar(250) NOT NULL,
[ID] varchar(250) NOT NULL,
[IntranetID] varchar(250) NULL,
[eMail] varchar(250) NULL,
[Number] varchar(50) NULL,
[ModifDate] datetime NULL)
ON [PRIMARY];
```

After truncating and inserting data again to this table, I'm unable to do a simple select query or a simple count query. The process tasks keeps running without ending. However I can query successfully on other tables except this one.

```
select * from Personas;
select count(*) from Personas;
```

How can I know the reason why this is happening and how can I fix it?
There are no error message on the queries so I don't know what are the errors. How can I know if the table was corrupted?

I'm not expert in SQL Server administration but I tried to execute below. I'm not sure if this is the reason, and how to fix this if it is.

```
DBCC SQLPERF(logspace)

Result:
Log Size (MB) = 19.6
Log Space Used (%) = 78.79
Status = 0
```

Please kindly help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have any open transactions? Try `SELECT @@TRANCOUNT`. It should be `0`. If it's not, that could cause the select statement to hang indefinitely.

Comment: Hi Tom, I tried it just now, the result is "0". Other tables are okay, except this one. Thanks.

Comment: How many rows are in the table? Truncating a table can cause performance issues because the query planner is not updated, and indexes may become fragmented.

Comment: Hi JohnnyBell, using toad table properties I can see that it have 16,000 rows. How can I know if my table is now corrupted? What can I do to try to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Try running `SELECT session_id,status 
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions
WHERE open_transaction_count > 0`

Comment: @TomChantler - `@@TRANCOUNT` will only give you if the current session has any open transaction. for blocking we will have to check all sessions

Comment: Hi Ughai, error in sql: Invalid column name 'open_transaction_count'. Thanks.

Comment: @@TRANCOUNT gives the current transaction count for the current _connection_, not the current _session_, but yeah, your command should work for SQL 2012 and newer.

Comment: create a primary key on the table

Comment: you can use them interchangeably , but if another _connection_ has an open transaction, it will not show up using `@@TRANCOUNT`  in the current connection

Comment: @Jemru - thats weird. Try to execute your select in one query window and in another query window run  `EXEC sp_who2` and look for a SPID value in `BlkBy` column

Comment: Hi Ughai. I executed EXEC sp_who2. There are Status = Sleeping. Command = Awaiting Command, CPU Time = 47929, BlkBy = "." Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

Try this,

```
select count(*) from Personas with (nolock)
```

Note:

if this query returns results then we can identify that your table is locked in some other session. You have to identify the session which blocks your table. Either you can kill that session or commit the transaction in it.

Answer (score 1):

For me disconnecting the SQl database and reconnecting it back helped to solve the problem.

The problem was while updating a table (few transactions have been triggered/ they need commit). So i just needed to commit the transactions and close it